# Excel Formula Matching Month and Year in Dynamic Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My first use of dynamic ranges. I am trying to build a payment table that outputs a static value with a row of years and a column of months. The formula referencing a dynamic range `=IF(AND(MONTH($F$3#)=$B21,YEAR($F$3#=C$11)),$D$3,0)`result is 0 in the example below. The Payment Schedule column is a dynamic formula created with `=EOMONTH(C3,SEQUENCE(B3,1,6,6))`. I have tried creating a dynamic range from `=MONTH(F3#)` and `=YEAR(F3#)`, and that gives me a month/year dynamic range, but using those instead of month in the formula also results in 0. I am expecting 112.00 in the 4 and 10 cells for each year. Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: Re "*I am expecting 112.00 in the 4 and 10 cells for each year.*", I don't see a result for month 4 of 2022. That said, in C12 you could try a further spill formula: `=IF(COUNTIFS(G3#,B12:B23,H3#,C11:E11),D3,0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AND()` function is not a row-wise function. Meaning, when you provide the `AND()` function with an array of TRUEs and FALSEs, if only one of the values is FALSE, the function will return FALSE. In other words, suppose you have two arrays of 4 values each, such that the `AND()` function looks like this: `AND({1,0,0,1},{1,1,1,0})` the function will return 0.

If I understand you correctly, in the case of the 2 example arrays above (`{1,0,0,1}` and `{1,1,1,0}`) you want the function to return 1.
To do that you can simply multiply the two arrays to do a row-wise AND calculation and then use the `OR()` function. The multiplication is possible even if the values are actually TRUEs and FALSEs instead of 1s and 0s.

For your formula that would spell out like this: `=IF(OR((MONTH($F$3#)=$B21)*(YEAR($F$3#)=C$11)),$D$3,0)`

### Edit 1: Fully Dynamic Solution

For a dynamic array solution of the months/years matrix of interest payments, the formula becomes significantly more complicated.

The solution **using the** `LET()` **function** would be

```
=LET(
    Dates,EDATE(DATE(YEAR($F$3),1,1),SEQUENCE(COUNT(UNIQUE(YEAR($F$3#)))*12)-1),
    Schedule,MATCH(Dates,DATE(YEAR($F$3#),MONTH($F$3#),1),0),
    IFERROR(INDEX(Schedule,MATCH(DATE($C$12#,$B$13#,1),Dates,0))^0*$D$3,0)
)
```

and the solution **without the** `LET()` **function** is

```
=IFERROR(
    INDEX(
        MATCH(
            EDATE(DATE(YEAR($F$3),1,1),SEQUENCE(COUNT(UNIQUE(YEAR($F$3#)))*12)-1),
            DATE(YEAR($F$3#),MONTH($F$3#),1),
            0),
        MATCH(
            DATE($C$12#,$B$13#,1),
            EDATE(DATE(YEAR($F$3),1,1),SEQUENCE(COUNT(UNIQUE(YEAR($F$3#)))*12)-1),
            0)
    )^0*$D$3,
    0
)
```

where the references `$C$12#` and `$B$13#` correspond to the months and years arrays shown in the screenshot here below

[image: Example Screeshot 1]

These months and years arrays have been generated with the formulas

1. for months `=SEQUENCE(12)`
2. for years `=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(YEAR(F3#)))`

### Edit 2: Partially Dynamic Solution

Since the months array is constant (always 1 to 12), it is not really necessary to generate the whole matrix through one complex formula, but break it up into 12 dynamic formulas.

The formula for a single month then becomes

```
=MMULT(
    SEQUENCE(1,COUNT($F$3#),1,0),
    (YEAR($F$3#)=$C$12#)*(MONTH($F$3#)=$B13)
)*$D$3
```

and has to be dragged down for all 12 months as shown in the screenshot here

[image: Example Screenshot 2]

Comment: There are some truly brilliant people on this site! Thanks Dattel, that worked.

Comment: I transposed the dynamic formula so it spills over columns instead of rows, Should I just duplicate the formula and add for additional payment rows, ie  `=IF(OR((MONTH($M$4#)=$B12)*(YEAR($M$4#)=C$11)),$J$4,0)+IF(OR((MONTH($M$5#)=$B12)*(YEAR($M$5#)=C$11)),$J$5,0)+...` or is there a better way? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there is an easier way :). I'll add it as an Edit to the answer above in 2-3 hours from now

Comment: I added 2 edits, the 1st showing a completely dynamic solution and the 2nd showing a partially dynamic solution. I would encourage you to use the second as it is significantly less complex.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I am looking for a solution for multiple rows of payments. So I transposed F3 to be `=TRANSPOSE(EOMONTH(C3,SEQUENCE(B3,1,6,6)))` so the Payment Schedule spilled over cells F3, G3, H3, I3, J3, and K3. (one/same row). Now I want to add another row. So B4=8, C4=102, and F4# is a new sequence of payment dates that spanned F4, G4, H4, I4, J4, K4, L4, M4. and also a different interest payment.

I can duplicate your original formula and add the results. I was asking if there is a better way to accomplish multiple rows of payments.

Comment: hmmm, it's difficult to picture it just based on the verbal description. Maybe it would be better if you create a new question for that problem

Comment: Will do, thanks Dattel

Comment: Just saw the new question. It's getting tricky! I'll give it try tomorrow if nobody else has answered it by then already.

Comment: Thanks Dattel. I think your edit 2 using mmult() is close, but I could not figure it out.