# Addition/Summarization of Multiple Dynamic Arrays into Month Year Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As a follow up to my previous question [Excel Formula Matching Month and Year in Dynamic Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74133108/excel-formula-matching-month-and-year-in-dynamic-range/74140012?noredirect=1#comment130927266_74140012)

I have a table of bonds and a month/year table below. Everything now works, but I have to duplicate the formula for each new bond I add to the table of bonds.

In the bond table the Payment Schedule is created with `=TRANSPOSE(EDATE(C4,SEQUENCE(B4,1,6,6)))`

In the month/year table, I create the years with the sequence `=TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(YEAR(MAX(E3:Z4))-YEAR(MIN(E3:Z4))+1,1,YEAR(MIN(E3:Z4))))`, and the cells in the table are created with `=IF(OR((MONTH($E$3#)=$B12)*(YEAR($E$3#)=C$11)),$D$3,0)+IF(OR((MONTH($E$4#)=$B12)*(YEAR($E$4#)=C$11)),$D$4,0)`

Is there a way to add additional bond rows without having to duplicate and add the formula in the month/year table as I will eventually exceed the formula max length. I'm trying for a pure function based solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your logic you could use the following in `C12`:

```
=SUM(
     BYROW($D$3:$P$6,
           LAMBDA(r,
                  LET(
                      values,TAKE(r,,1),
                      dates,DROP(r,,1),
IF(OR((MONTH(dates)=$B12)*(YEAR(dates)=C$11)),values,0)))))
```

It uses BYROW to "loop" through the `Interest Payment` values and the `Payment Schedule` date values.
LET is used to separate the  values (first column values from range by row) from the dates (all other columns,except the first from the range by row).
Then your IF-function repeats itself with the values and dates row by row. Since this would spill per row I wrapped it in SUM, so the sum of each rows result is the outcome.

[image]

You still have to drag the formula to the other cells, like your own formula, but if you append a row of data to your payments data table, it's a matter of changing `$D$3:$P$6` to `$D$3:$P$7` and row 7 would be included as well.

Comment: The new BYROW, BYCOL, LAMBDA, LET, TAKE and DROP functions are powerful. Way beyond the old days of array formulas! I'll have to freshen my skills. Thank you for taking the time, and for your solution.

Comment: You're welcome. It was a fun question to work with.

Answer (score 1):

For a solution that works without the 'newer' functions such as BYROW, BYCOL, LAMBDA, LET, TAKE and DROP, the following formula works too:

```
=MMULT(
    SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS($E$3:$N$4)*ROWS($E$3:$N$4),1,0),
    (YEAR(INDEX($E$3:$N$4,INT(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS($E$3:$N$4)*ROWS($E$3:$N$4),1,0)/COLUMNS($E$3:$N$4))+1,MOD(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS($E$3:$N$4)*ROWS($E$3:$N$4),1,0),COLUMNS($E$3:$N$4))+1))=$C$11#)
        *(MONTH(INDEX($E$3:$N$4,INT(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS($E$3:$N$4)*ROWS($E$3:$N$4),1,0)/COLUMNS($E$3:$N$4))+1,MOD(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS($E$3:$N$4)*ROWS($E$3:$N$4),1,0),COLUMNS($E$3:$N$4))+1))=$B12)
        *INDEX($D$3:$D$4,INT(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS($E$3:$N$4)*ROWS($E$3:$N$4),1,0)/COLUMNS($E$3:$N$4))+1)
)
```

Although there is quite a lot of redundant calculation in there since LET is not available.

What this is doing essentially is illustrated in this simplified (non-functional) formula:

```
=MMULT(
    vector_of_ones,
    (years_bonds=years_matrix)*(months_bonds=month_matrix)*(interest_payments)
)
```

This solution can be pasted in `C12` and then dragged down.

Note that the input array `$E$3:$N$4` for the payment schedule and `$D$3:$D$4` for the interest payments is hard written into the formula. Meaning, these would have to be extended in the formula manually or replaced by an `OFFSET()` or `FILTER()` array that adjust automatically. It is also possible to already allow for a larger array here, e.g. `$E$3:$N$10` and `$D$3:$D$10` as long as those extra rows are empty.  A 3rd solution would be to create a dynamic arrays out of the input arrays elsewhere and only referring to those intermediary dynamic arrays without the need to make any changes to the final formula.

See screenshot for an example.

[image: Example Screenshot 1]

Comment: I have a recent version so BYROW, BYCOL, LAMBDA, LET, TAKE and DROP are available to me. Thank you for the effort you put into this Dattel.